# Windows 10 denies HTTP delete requests

Tags: jquery, http, https, windows-10

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/758nhbf8) snippet works with the current version of Chromium, Chrome or Internet Explorer in IE10 emulation mode on the following systems:

- Windows 10 Home
- Windows 10 Premium
- Ubuntu 14.04

But I have one Windows 10 Home machine here that rejects the delete request (I think on the client site, as I do not even receive the request on the server side) with the following error message in Chrome:

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

And this one in IE:

```
Script7002: XMLHttpRequest network error 0x2f78 could not complete the operation due to error 00002f78
```

When switching to this [https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/758nhbf8) everything works fine on the denying machine. So I wonder, if I do miss something special here.

Somebody experienced this behaviour or knows about anything RFC like, that mentions this behaviour?
If I exchange Jquery with f.e. AngularJS, it still behaves the same. If I do use PUT, GET oder POST instead of DELETE requests I receive a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody in the microsoft community recommended updating the windows system to build 10586 - that did not have any impact and the problem still exists in the same way.